# What happens when a user clicks "Stop Publishing Activity from <appname>" and "Remove <appname>"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publishing

I've noticed on Facebook that posts that have been made from a 3rd party app have the above mentioned menu options when clicking the "Edit or Remove" button in the top right corner of each post on your timeline.

I am curious what the implications are if a user selects "Stop Publishing Activity from " or "Remove "?

Is there a way to detect when this happens? Does it register data in insights?

Does it just revoke the app's permissions to publish to the user's wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an app triggers a call to the callback URL you can set up for exactly that purpose in your app settings.

And stop publishing will just revoke the related permissions, I’d guess.